# wp-admin/admin-ajax.php - Slowing My Site down

Tags: homepage

Whenever I do a speed test on my site from Pingdom - the page wp-admin/admin-ajax.php takes the longest to load and therefore it is causing my site to load slowly.

As speed is an important factor I would like some advice. [This is the site.](http://www.ticketreview.net/)

Answer (score 3):

*admin-ajax.php* is called with the following `action: wpp_update`. Look for whatever this action does, it may be doing a remote request, a big query, or something else that takes a long time to execute.

A quick search for `wpp_update` reveals the plugin to be [`WordPress Popular Posts`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/).

This function is being called http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-popular-posts/tags/2.2.1/wordpress-popular-posts.php#L360

There are quite a few queries there, but you'll have to [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) them yourself in order to find out how long the whole function takes to complete. The function appears to work for 1-4 seconds there but does not return any content; unless something depends on its "OK" response there (as far as I see, it doesn't), it does not prevent the site from showing the other content immediately and should not raise any concerns whatsoever. It's non-blocking.